# Count how many occurences are greater or equel of a defined value in a line

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I've a file (F1) with N=10000 lines, each line contains M=20000 numbers. I've an other file (F2) with N=10000 lines with only 1 column. How can count the number of occurences in line i of file F2 that are greater or equal to the number found at line i in the file F2 ? I tried using a bash loop with awk / sed but my output is empty.

Edit >
For now I've only succeed to print the number of occurences that are higher than a defined value. Here an example with a file with 3 lines and a defined value of 15 (sorry it's a very dirty code ..) :

```
for i in {1..3};do sed -n "$i"p tmp.txt | sed 's/\t/\n/g' | awk '{if($1 > 15){print $1}}' | wc -l; done;
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the "bash loop with awk / sed" that you've tried, and then we can help you correct it.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1;next}
        {count=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
          {if($i >= a[FNR])
            {count++}
          };
        print count
        }' file2 file1
```

While processing file2, total line record is equal to line record of current file, store value in array a with current record as index.

initialize count to 0 for each line.
loop through the fields, increment the counter if value is greater or equal at current FNR index in array a.
Print the count value

```
$ cat file1
1 3 5 7 3 6
2 5 6 8 7 7
4 6 7 8 9 4

$ cat file2
6
3
1

$ awk -f file.awk
2
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a single awk command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1;next}{c=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)c+=($i>a[FNR]);print c}' file2 file1
```